# How to make a user re-input data if input does not equal a case in the switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement, default

I recently learned Java and I have a `switch` statement that gets user input *from another class* and i was wondering how to make the `default` `case` for my `switch` statement make the user re-input data.

Currently I have the following basic code

```
static int getMonthInt(String monthName) 
{
    switch(monthName.trim()) 
    {
        case "January":
            return 1;
        case "Febuary":
            return 2;
        case "March":
            return 3;
        case "April":
            return 4;
        case "May":
            return 5;
        case "June":
            return 6;
        case "July":
            return 7;
        case "August":
            return 8;
        case "September":
            return 9;
        case "October":
            return 10;
        case "November":
            return 11;
        case "December":
            return 12;
        default:
            // what do i put here
    }
    
}
```

I get user input from an input class called from another class like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String monthName;
    int dayNumber;
    int yearNumber;
    
    monthName = Input.getString("Please enter the current month name with a capital letter!");
    dayNumber = Input.getInt("Please enter the current day!");
    yearNumber = Input.getInt("Please enter the current year!"); }
```

This all works. My problem is however that **if someone enters an invalid input such as 'ovtomber' I want the user to be re-prompted to enter data.** Would I put this in the default case of the switch or in the main method (where I get user input) also how would i do this (I tried both ways and couldnt get the expected behavior & I could not find any topics on input validation)?

Comment: Put the `switch` inside a loop.

Comment: or think of `recursing`?

Comment: Return an invalid value (eg `-1`), and check for that outside the method.  If invalid value, ask user again.

Comment: Any integer value will give an error as the switch is called through the getMonthInt method which (ironically) takes a String as a parameter. So any non-string inputs will cause the program to end with an error message. However, i want to make the user re-input data if they enter a STRING thats not a month name with a capital letter

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Ian thanks that is a good solution to this question do you mind putting that as an answer and ill accept it? (Sorry to reactivate an old thread, since my post history had some downvoted posts like this, I am banned from asking new questions until I edit these questiona such that they are no longer downvoted to a negative total :/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your switch statement you have the default return an obviously invalid month (commonly -1):

```
default:
    return -1;
```

Then in your logic, you can request clarification if the result is `-1`, eg:

```
int validatedMonth;
do
{
    monthName = Input.getString("Please enter the current month name with a capital letter!");
    validatedMonth = getMonthInt(monthName);
    if(validatedMonth == -1)
        System.out.println("Invalid month name, please try again");
} while (validatedMonth == -1);
```

(example code, I haven't checked it compiles)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can return 0 in the default case.

And in the main function

```
while(getMonthInt(String monthName) ==0){
/*get user input here*/
}
```

Then it will make user to keep giving input if it is default